# Weighting Prospects

Tags: organization

I'll be entering quite a few "Uncontacted" Organisations and Individuals into my CRM.
The next phase is to speak to them. 
Is there some way to list Organisations at "Hot, medium, cold" or like one would do in Salesforce type of program?
Thanks,
Jeremy

Comment: Is there any reason you wouldn't just use tags, groups, or custom fields to store this information? What is distinctive about the Salesforce offering?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach would be to have a custom Activity Type for "Lead follow up" with a custom field on it for eg Hot / Cold, then you can

- create the Activity for new Orgs
- set a Due Date
- assign it to someone
- have any additional custom fields you want to record more info
- set a 'follow up' activity.

I think compared with Salesforce the issue here is that civicrm is highly flexible and let's you make something which matches the desired work flow.

Comment: Excellent Pete! Thanks so much for the suggestion, sounds perfect!

Comment: Great. so the StackExchange 'protocol' is that you would +1 the answer and Accept it. But of course you can defer doing so in case other better answers come along. But SE doesn't like questions that have answers but without ever being 'accepted'